# Зачем нужен RxJava в Android?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

В хабре вычитал кучу уроков и статьей по RX. Все приводят прмиеры с проблемным asyncTaskom который может не правильно запрос обработать и null выдать или еще чего. Дак для этого нужно exception нужно обрабатывать. А насчет запросов Retrofit же есть. Ну ни как не пойму полезность RXJava. Зачем он нужен вообще?

Comment: Вы пробовали ввести заголовок Вашего вопроса в Google? Если результаты Вас не устроили, то стоит указать в тексте вопроса какие моменты кажутся неясными.

Comment: Если вы не видите проблем, которые мог бы решить `RxJava`, значит он вам не нужен.

Comment: во https://blog.mindorks.com/a-complete-guide-to-learn-rxjava-b55c0cea3631

Comment: @defaultlocale, да я искал в гугле, там индуз один сказал что rxJava это ересь и придумали его чтобы деньги заработать. Также как и Apple вот и все. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

RxJava - это библиотека, которая реализует реактивный подход к программированию. Что такое реактивное программирование можно почитать на сайте проекта [ReactiveX API](http://reactivex.io/).

> ReactiveX is a combination of the best ideas from the Observer
>   pattern, the Iterator pattern, and functional programming
>
> ReactiveX - это комбинация лучших идей шаблонов проектирования `Наблюдатель` и
>   `Итератор` и функционального программирования.

Если совсем простыми словами, то это подход при котором вы оперируете событиями и потоками данных. Т.е. вместо "запустили и ждем результат" или "как отработает 
 надо запустить callback и передать в него результат" вы говорите "Вот тебе труба, сиди и смотри на нее. Как только в нее посыпятся данные - обработай их, а я пошел дальше".

Большей частью такой подход полезен для создании асинхронных приложений и  изничтожения [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)'а.

Если совсем грубо, то у вас появляются такие сущности как `Observer`(наблюдатель) и `Observable`(наблюдаемое). Наблюдатель наблюдает за наблюдаемым и, когда из наблюдаемого посыпались события(объекты) - производит с потоком этих событий какие либо действия. В частности никто не мешает ему быть "Наблюдаемым" для другого "наблюдателя" например.

Представьте себе длинную комнату с множеством стоящих рядом коробок(наблюдаемое). У каждой коробки стоит рабочий(наблюдатель) и, как только ему в коробку упал объект - он берет его, что-то с ним делает, кладет в следующую по очереди коробку и берет следующий объект. Самый цимус в том, что разные этапы обработки не завязаны друг на друга, т.е. все рабочие работают одновременно - пока последний обрабатывает объект №1, который прошел уже почти весь конвейер, рабочий из середины работает с объектом №5, а первый рабочий уже стоит курит и ждет, когда из дыры в стене повалят новые объекты.

Comment: Стремление из графа сделать трубу с очередью может породить не менее уродский pipe-hell, сложность отладки, поддержки и модификации. Если написана цепочка на rx и она работает, не трогайте ее никогда. Нужна модификация, лучше начните писать цепочку заново. Есть вариант новую цепочку не писать: забить на rx.

Answer (score 0):

Java своим синтаксисом не позволяет использовать паттерны реактивного программирования. RxJava позволяет писать программы в реактивном стиле

Comment: ну, как бы, `RxJava` написан на `Java`

Comment: Да, все верно, `RxJava` написан на `Java`, мне известно об этом

Comment: тогда зачем вы вводите в заблуждение человека словами `Java своим синтаксисом не позволяет использовать паттерны реактивного программирования`?

Comment: Я не ввожу человека в заблуждение, Java действительно не содержит никаких конструкций на уровне языка, позволяющих писать программы в реактивном стиле

Comment: Раз `RxJava` написан на `Java`, и он очень даже себе реактивен, то логично предположить, что Java таки позволяет писать код в таком стиле. Более того, можно даже и без RxJava обойтись

Comment: Увы, писать программы средставами языка не одно и то же, что писать программы средствами фреймворка, написанного средствами языка. А как писать в реактивном стиле без RxJava  и подобных RxJava библиотек?

Comment: Например написать собственную реализацию

Comment: Но чем этот вариант будет отличаться от RxJava? Вы часто пишите свои реализации вместо использования готовых инструментов?

Comment: Другими словами вы сами понятия не имеете для какой цели нужен RXJava

Comment: Просветите меня